# Is this an on-topic question?

Tags: discussion, scope, on-topic-definition

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/44/sufi-populations-in-the-united-states-and-overall

Should this question be on-topic? It is asking more about the demographics than the religion.

Comment: I am up voting this, meaning I agree with you. I think those who disagree can up vote @HaLaBi 's answer, so we can see what majority thinks.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is. The question is asking about:

> What percentage of population do Sufis make up in a special
>   region/country?

It's valid question because:

- It's mainly about the religion or one of its sects.
- It's about population density which is an important aspect of study about every religion.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion. it totally fits in here.

Answer (score 2):

The site is broad. The question has to do with finding out some information about practitioners of Islam, and it's something that people might presumably find interesting. So I vote it's on-topic but perhaps close to the boundary.

Answer (score -4):

I do not think this is an on-topic question for this site.

This question deals with demographics and data. If you have a question about data, commit to [this proposal.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37195/data) It should be off-topic here.

Comment: Sure it's about data, but it's data *about* Muslims. So I think it's totally on topic.